# Как мне сохранить Player в JSON, вместе с интерфейсами

Tags: json, интерфейс, gson

У меня есть некий класс `Player`. У него есть как у всех подобных классов:
`hp`, `mp`, `level`, `xp`. Но ведь этого мало, не так ли?

У моего класса есть еще `Weapon` (оружие) и `Effects` (пассивные эффекты). 
Само же `Weapon` и `Effect` -- интерфейсы.

Как мне все это чудо сохранить в JSON или еще какой-то формат, что бы когда я загрузил игру, мог восстановить данные, включая имплементации (реализации)?

Comment: С помощью сериализатора и десериализатора

Comment: Просто серриадизатор и десеализатор не поможет. Он не поддерживает сериализацию Имплементаций. Но вот как-то же имя класса хранить можно же

Comment: Сериализуются не интерфейсы, а объекты. И с этим всё впорядке

Comment: Вижу только единое решение: Хранить данные в промежуточных DTO, и создать метод, который создеает соответственную имплементацию по реализации (берет имя класса из DTO)